# how to create android linearlayout Tag?

Tags: android, layout, tags

I saw an application and the tag search was good. I just want the layout of the search tag. If you know, send me that tag. Below is some detail with some image below.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I think you are looking for is a `View` called `Chip` and they are typically contained within a `ChipGroup`.

I have looked through this article, it should have everything you need.

https://www.journaldev.com/21994/android-p-chips-chipgroup